# Android Library - separate only graphics

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to separate the code of an app into a library (I made the project Library) and then just creating new project, that would only replace the drawables with other resources? Everything else needs to stay the same, just the graphics different.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Straightforward. You'll need an individual manifest at least, though. ;)

Comment: but how would the new project know that it has to start the project from the library? Do I change the <application> parameters in the Application to match something from the Library?

Comment: @user584513 You'll sure have to have a manifest which references your main activity's class name from the library, yes. Have you educated yourself about the nature of the [manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)?